# PySpark: Convert RDD to List

Tags: list, pyspark, rdd

I am having trouble converting an RDD to a list, and I could use some help seeing where I am going wrong.

Here is what I am working with:

This RDD has 49995 elements, and was created using this function:

```
testList = myData.map(extract_values)

testList.take(1)

[[SparseVector(49995, {1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 1.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 1.0, 9: 1.0, 10: 1.0, 11: 1.0, 12: 1.0, 13: 1.0, 14: 1.0, 15: 1.0, 16: 1.0, 17: 1.0, 18: 1.0, 19: 1.0, 20: 1.0, 21: 1.0, 22: 1.0, 23: 1.0, 24: 1.0, 25: 1.0, 26: 1.0, 27: 1.0, 28: 1.0, 29: 1.0, 30: 1.0, 31: 1.0, 32: 1.0, 33: 1.0, 34: 1.0, 35: 1.0, 36: 1.0, 37: 1.0, 38: 1.0, 39: 1.0, 40: 1.0, 41: 1.0, 42: 1.0, 43: 1.0, 44: 1.0, 45: 1.0, 46: 1.0, 47: 1.0, 48: 1.0, 49: 1.0, 50: 1.0, 51: 1.0, 52: 1.0, 53: 1.0, 54: 1.0, 55: 1.0, 56: 1.0, 57: 1.0, 58: 1.0, 59: 1.0, 60: 1.0, 61: 1.0, 62: 1.0, 63: 1.0, 64: 1.0, 65: 1.0, 66: 1.0, 67: 1.0, 68: 1.0, 69: 1.0, 70: 1.0, 71: 1.0, 72: 1.0, 73: 1.0, 74: 1.0, 75: 1.0, 76: 1.0, 77: 1.0, 78: 1.0, 79: 1.0, 80: 1.0, 81: 1.0, 82: 1.0, 83: 1.0, 84: 1.0, 85: 1.0, 86: 1.0, 87: 1.0, 88: 1.0, 89: 1.0, 90: 1.0, 91: 1.0, 92: 1.0, 93: 1.0, 94: 1.0})]]
```

The extract_values function is:

```
def extract_values(friendRDD):
    list = []
    list.append(friendRDD[1])
    return list
```

At this point, I have tried:

```
myList = myData.map(extract_values).collect()
```

but it gives an error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

which I do not have any clue on why it is giving this error output.

How can I convert the testList RDD into a list at this point?

Here is the myData.take(1):

```
 [(0, SparseVector(49995, {1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 1.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 1.0, 9: 1.0, 10: 1.0, 11: 1.0, 12: 1.0, 13: 1.0, 14: 1.0, 15: 1.0, 16: 1.0, 17: 1.0, 18: 1.0, 19: 1.0, 20: 1.0, 21: 1.0, 22: 1.0, 23: 1.0, 24: 1.0, 25: 1.0, 26: 1.0, 27: 1.0, 28: 1.0, 29: 1.0, 30: 1.0, 31: 1.0, 32: 1.0, 33: 1.0, 34: 1.0, 35: 1.0, 36: 1.0, 37: 1.0, 38: 1.0, 39: 1.0, 40: 1.0, 41: 1.0, 42: 1.0, 43: 1.0, 44: 1.0, 45: 1.0, 46: 1.0, 47: 1.0, 48: 1.0, 49: 1.0, 50: 1.0, 51: 1.0, 52: 1.0, 53: 1.0, 54: 1.0, 55: 1.0, 56: 1.0, 57: 1.0, 58: 1.0, 59: 1.0, 60: 1.0, 61: 1.0, 62: 1.0, 63: 1.0, 64: 1.0, 65: 1.0, 66: 1.0, 67: 1.0, 68: 1.0, 69: 1.0, 70: 1.0, 71: 1.0, 72: 1.0, 73: 1.0, 74: 1.0, 75: 1.0, 76: 1.0, 77: 1.0, 78: 1.0, 79: 1.0, 80: 1.0, 81: 1.0, 82: 1.0, 83: 1.0, 84: 1.0, 85: 1.0, 86: 1.0, 87: 1.0, 88: 1.0, 89: 1.0, 90: 1.0, 91: 1.0, 92: 1.0, 93: 1.0, 94: 1.0}))],
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It isn't necessarily a source of error since `friendRDD` could be anything, but just in case, I want to check to make sure you know Python list indices [begin at zero.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Comment: Since you're able to `take` an element from your RDD after mapping, you should be able to `collect` them all in the same way. The likely reason for this to be a problem would be if your source RDD contains some problematic rows and some non-problematic rows, and `take(1)` happened to choose a non-problematic row.

Comment: To diagnose, check the source data (your `myData` RDD) for any "weird" records. Based on what the `ValueError` says, I'd especially keep an eye out for any vector fields that have an empty (or other non-integer) key.

Comment: @Jesse Amano I understand that the python indices begin at 0. I'll post the myData take(1) above. I intended to take the [1] element of the vector.

Comment: Ok, just checking ;)
I still think you might have some rows in the RDD that don't have the exact same schema as the first row, since `take(1)` worked with that row but `collect()` didn't. There aren't any syntactical errors in what you've posted here, so it must be an issue with the data source.